# Boot Loader - How to move forward compiling with C

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I have just finished writing a fairly extensive boot loader in assembly. Right now, it prints a boot message, waits for key input, and reboots the system and repeats that process continuously.

What I want to know is, how can I move forward with this? I'm somewhat lost as to where to go now. I have a feeling that I am going to need to compile C programs with the boot loader but I am completely unsure how to do this.

I have been reading up on the OSDev wiki and it doesn't seem like they offer any concrete tutorials on how to compile C programs from the boot loader.

Here is my boot loader code in assembly.

```
; --------------------------------------------------------
; ZOS - Header Information
; --------------------------------------------------------

BITS 16                 ; BIOS starts out in 16-bit real mode
ORG 0                   ; TODO - Find standard ORG point
jmp start               ; Skip over data and functions

; --------------------------------------------------------
; ZOS - Global Data Section
; --------------------------------------------------------

boot_msg    db  'Booting ZOS - 1.0.0'       , 0
reboot_msg  db  'Press any key to reboot...'    , 0
endofline   db  13, 10              , 0

; --------------------------------------------------------
; ZOS - Function Definitions
; --------------------------------------------------------

; --------------------------------------------------------
; Print  function
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Input:
; - String contained in 'si'
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Output:
; - String contained in 'si' to screen
; - Does not print a new line after return
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Message Declaration:
; > message db 'Your Message'
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Printing Usage:
; > mov si, message
; > call print
; --------------------------------------------------------
print:
    mov ah, 0Eh         ; 'int 10h' print char function
print_cont:
    lodsb               ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0           ; Check if character is 0
    je print_done           ; If character is 0, done
    int 10h             ; Otherwise, print character
    jmp print_cont          ; Continue printing string
print_done:
    ret             ; We are done printing, return

; --------------------------------------------------------
; Wait for input function
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Input:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Output:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Calling Usage:
; > call pause
; --------------------------------------------------------
pause:
    mov ah, 0           ; Wait for key
    int 016h            ; keyboard function
    ret             ; Return

; --------------------------------------------------------
; Reboot function
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Input:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Output:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Calling Usage:
; > call reboot
; --------------------------------------------------------
reboot:
    db 0EAh
    dw 0000h
    dw 0FFFFh

; --------------------------------------------------------
; ZOS - Main Starting Function
; --------------------------------------------------------

; --------------------------------------------------------
; Main Starting Function
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Input:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
; Output:
; - None
; --------------------------------------------------------
start:                  
    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288         ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax          ; Set 'ss' to the beinning of the stack
    mov sp, 4096            ; Set 'ss:sp' to the beinning of the stack

    mov ax, 07C0h           ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax          ; Set 'ds' to this location

    mov si, boot_msg        ; Load the boot message
    call print          ; Call the print function

    mov si, endofline       ; Load a line terminator
    call print          ; Call the print function

    mov si, reboot_msg      ; Load the reboot message
    call print          ; Call the print function

    mov si, endofline       ; Load a line terminator
    call print          ; Call the print function

    call pause          ; Wait for a key press
    call reboot         ; Reboot the system

; --------------------------------------------------------
; ZOS - Footer Information
; --------------------------------------------------------

times 510-($-$$) db 0           ; Fill the remainder of the bootloader with 0's
dw 0xAA55               ; Standard PC boot signature at the end
```

Any tips on how I can write in parts to load C files and compile and run them would be helpful. Any other tips and advice you can give me on boot loaders and operating system construction would be also greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have a feeling that I am going to need to compile C programs with the boot loader**

You don't have to write C programs at all. Why don't you code entirely in assembler? Anyhow if you do write programs in any language you would always compile them into an executable form.

Some remarks on your bootloader:
a. The print routine should also provide the BX register as a parameter to the BIOS teletype function.
b. If you want to setup a 4KB stack right after the bootloader you must add AX,32 and not AX,288 (which leaves a memory hole of 4KB beneath the stack)
c. It's best to `cli` and `sti` when changing the SS and SP registers. A bootloader does not always choose the exact architecture it will be running in.

```
cli
mov ss, ax          ; Set 'ss' to the beinning of the stack
mov sp, 4096        ; Set 'ss:sp' to the **END** of the stack
sti                                        ^^^
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the input and clarifications, I have some followup concerns however.

Could you at least point me in the direction of how I could go about compiling C code from my boot loader even though you feel I should write it all in assembly?

Also, could you explain what cli and sti do?

Comment: @UnmercifulTurtle boot loaders don't compile code (usually). They only load code already compiled by a compiler before and linked with the boot loader somehow. See e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader. As for what `cli` and `sti` do lookup their definition in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). Studying an open source hobby OS and joining it's development team might be good idea (e.g. http://www.menuetos.net)

Comment: CLI makes sure that no interrupts will occur between changing the SS register and the SP register. If such an interrupt were to happen the stackpointer SS:SP would be in a incorrect state with probably disatrous results! (A modern CPU already does a CLI when writing to SS but in a bootloader I think you should do it explicitely)

Comment: **Could you at least point me in the direction of how I could go about compiling C code from my boot loader** This would require you to write a complete C-compiler in the bootloader or more feasible in the kernal loaded by the bootloader. Are you willing to undertake such an adventure?

Answer (score 0):

Running "C" programs requires a C library

You have 2 options:

- Load some kind of operating system with C library.
- Link your boot loader with objects from C library.

If you choose the second option, you can to add .c files to the projects, compile them with a C compiler, and link the created objects with your exiting bootlader objects.
The linker will add objects from the C library to the link, or you may add your own implementation of functions such as printf(), memcpy(), etc.

In addition, you will need to create a link script file, allocate a stack, zero BSS, and jump to C code.